# How to solve an error in R: Couldn't find a sufficient Python binary

Tags: python, r, argparse

I'm going to use a implentation package downloaded from Github. In the scripts there is one line:

```
parser <- ArgumentParser(add_help = F)
```

I tried to run this, but it gives me error:

```
parser <- ArgumentParser(add_help = F)
   Error in findpython::find_python_cmd(required_modules = required_modules) :
```

> Couldn't find a sufficient Python binary. If you haven't installed the
> Python dependency yet please do so. If you have but it isn't on the
> system path (as is default on Windows) please add it to path or set
> options('python_cmd'='/path/to/binary')  or set the PYTHON, PYTHON2,
> or PYTHON3 environmental variables.   Python must have access to the
> modules: argparse, json | simplejson

I'm pretty sure I download python3.10.2 and install to default path.

So to make sure R knows the right path to Python, here is what I do:

```
> library(reticulate)
> py_config()
python:         C:/Users/Ciel Yuxi Yao/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/Ciel Yuxi Yao/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python310.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/Ciel Yuxi Yao/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310
version:        3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:           [NOT FOUND]
```

Then I want to check if I have the module "argparse" and "json" or "simplejson" as required.

```
 py_module_available(module="argparse")
[1] TRUE
> py_module_available(module="json")
[1] TRUE
```

It seems I have everything, why there's still error in R telling me it can't find python module?

Then I start to think what if I tell R the path directly. Here's what I do:

```
options(python_cmd="C:/Users/Ciel Yuxi Yao/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310")
```

When I run the lines again:

```
> parser <- ArgumentParser(add_help = F)
Error in assert_python_cmd(python_cmd) : 
  python executable C:/Users/Ciel Yuxi Yao/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310 either is not installed, is not on the path, or does not have argparse, json modules please see INSTALL file
```

New error shows up and still couldn't find the module.

I double check my R version and python version, they are both 64-bit and R4.1.0, python3.10.2. In the github README file these versions are totally fine for the package.

Could someone help me figure out what's going on with the code, why it doesn't work?